How to create a custom form template from admin panel?
I had used web-forms extension which was a very good solution but my main problem is it is only allowing to create 10 fields whereas my form contains 18 fields... please provide a solution for this... thanks in advance

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
